# Let L CFL. Prove or disprove $B(L) = \{w : w \in L, |w|>10 \} $ is CFL

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I'm struggling with proving or disproving this question. 
 I didn't find any counterexamples, so I tend to think that I need to prove it.

$L$ is $CFL$, so exist $CFG$, $G=(V,Σ,R,S)$ that accepts $L$. 
 From here I'm not sure how should I build $B(L)$ (if proving is the correct answer).

Some suggestions would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $CFL$ in your question?

Comment: The key here is that $\{w : w \in L, |w|\le 10 \}$ is finite, and therefore regular. From there, all you need are closure properties.

Comment: L could be any Context-free language. @JovanRadenkovic
As a result, I believe $\{w:w∈L,|w|≤10\}$ is not necessarily finite.

Comment: @yuval: the alphabet is finite. So the number of possible strings of bounded length is finite. It doesn't matter what the language is. (Of course, the number of strings whose length is greater than 10 is not necessarily finite. But that's not the point.)